# How to toggle a force

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm looking for a way to apply a force to an object after one button press (using GetKeyDown), essentially toggling the force.

I've had trouble for a few days trying to work this out as I'm learning how to use C#. I'm trying to work out a slide or dash for a 2D platformer, akin to Megaman sliding. This is my code so far, however when I press G, it teleports me forward instead of giving me a set velocity over time (where I want the player to move steadily foward)

```
public float slideCount;
public float maxSlideCount;
public bool isSliding; 

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.G) && isSliding == false) {
            slideCount += Time.deltaTime;
            isSliding = true;

            if (slideCount < maxSlideCount) {
                rb2d.AddRelativeForce (Vector2.right * 0.05f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            } else
                slideCount = 0;

            isSliding = false;
        }
```

Appreciate it

Comment: Whats the point in setting isSliding to true, and then instantly setting it to false?

Comment: You should also add some context to where you are doing this...  and some idea as to what your variables are...

Comment: Force gives you acceleration so if you want your player to move at a constant velocity i suggest using translation instead of force

Comment: Alright that helps a little... firstly, your isSliding variable is useless, it does nothing for you.  Also, do not use translation if you are using unity's Physics.

Comment: I'll be fixing the isSliding variable when I work out how to get the velocity working the way I want, so that's no biggy. Yes I am using unity's physics

Comment: My bad I linked the 3d ForceModes, did you attempt to use the other 2D forcemode?  .Force

Comment: Also, I would recommend attempting to just use `AddForce`

Comment: I just attempted to use .Force, however this still results in the player object teleporting forward instead of sliding forward (persisted when changing to AddForce too)

Comment: @BenjaminZarb can you share a screenshot of your rigidbody2d settings?

Comment: [Here it is](http://prntscr.com/lw2adr) The player material, is 0 friction 0 bounciness

Comment: change your interpolate from none to interpolate.

Comment: Okay thanks! Now that that's fixed, how would I go about making it less _zippy_ he's still a bit quick?

Comment: Use less force.

Answer (score 0):

So a standard toggle looks like:

```
void Update() { // User-interactions happen in the graphics-frame
    if (inputDown) {
        toggle = !toggle;
    }
}
```

Then to use `toggle`:

```
void fixedUpdate() { // Because you're applying forces, do it in the physics-frame
    if (toggle) {
        myRigidBody.AddForce(...);
    }
}
```